# How can you store an xhtml page in xml CDATA?

Tags: xml, xhtml, cdata

I need to grab the xhtml source from a site and store it in an xml file, however the xhtml contains CDATA and since nested CDATA is not allowed I'm not sure what to do. Is there any simple solution to this or is there some easy way to covert the xhtml to html? Thanks for any help.

Comment: If it's well-formed XHTML, why not just drop it in the XML as an XML fragment?

Comment: It needs to be contained in CDATA for now, so is the only way to get this is to convert it to html somehow then? If so do you know of any simple method using python preferably?

Comment: So I found a quick hack which seems to work thanks to http://web-design.blogs.webucator.com/2010/11/20/nesting-cdata-blocks/
I just ended up replacing '//]]' with '//]]]]><![CDATA[>' which worked smoothly. I'd post this in answers, but apparently is to soon.

Comment: Every CDATA can be converted into non-CDATA. Go ahead, do it, problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting XML content in CDATA sections is generally a bad idea (it's an abuse of CDATA, for a start: by putting something in CDATA you are saying "there is no markup in here"). Nesting CDATA seems doubly bad. But you've got yourself into this hole, and you're determined to dig yourself in deeper, so you can do it if you try. Just replace the `]]>` that terminates a CDATA section with `]]]><![CDATA[[`.